# .Value prints as Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBBool instead of 'true' or 'false'

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When trying to Console.Writeline the output of a DynamoDB query (a document), I get "Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBBool" instead of the "true" or "False" value. How to print the correct ToString() representation of any given value coming from DynamoDB whether its a string or int or boolean.

```
foreach (var resultDocument in resultDocs)
{
    foreach (var resultDocItem in resultDocument)
    {
      printString += $",{resultDocItem.Value.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

This code prints "Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBBool" when a boolean value is hit rather than 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get out of the `foreach` is a `KeyValuePair<string, DynamoDBEntry>` which has the default `ToString()`. To get the string representation of what you actually want you'll need to use the built cast operators to get back to the actual value you're looking for.

Specifically for `DynamoDBBool` it could look like this:

```
var doc = new Document();
doc.Add("aaa", new DynamoDBBool(true));
foreach(var item in doc)
{
    var s = item.Value is DynamoDBBool ? item.Value.AsBoolean().ToString() : item.Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {s}");
}
```

To more easily cover all options we can use the fact that a `doc` is just a JSON document of key value pairs. This takes the doc to JSON and then prints the proper string representations of each entry.

```
var doc = new Document();
doc.Add("aaa", new DynamoDBBool(true));
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(doc.ToJson());
foreach(var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the "print the correct ToString() representation of any given value coming from DynamoDB whether its a string or int or boolean". It seems like you would need to make a long list type checking each variation in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDynamoDBEntry.html unless there's another mechanic in the API.

Comment: @ShortFuse This is just to satisfy the the bool, that's why I say _you'll need to use the built in cast operators_. That is a long list and gives me a new idea. Will edit

Comment: I had the same idea of JSON. I'm not able to test it at the moment, but asPrimitive() could also be a solution based on https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.ArbitraryDataMapping.html 

Either way, it seems you're on the right track. Good luck!